# Big path on git add file

Tags: node.js, windows, git, libgit2

I tried add one of node.js module to git project. But add operation failed:

```
libgit2 returned: Invalid path for filesystem 'E:/Projects/vsteams/node_modules/gulp-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/decompress/node_modules/decompress-tar/node_modules/strip-dirs/node_modules/is-natural-number/is-natural-number-cjs.js': Data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

Is this windows problem or problem with libgit2 realization on windows (windows 7 by the way)? It looked like problem with big system path (276 symbols). May be some sulution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The message does indeed come from the path being too long for the Win32 calls we perform. libgit2 does not currently support long paths on Windows. It may do so at some point, since git itself has set a precedent, but it likely won't be in the short term.